# Black information boxes on certain icons/links all over chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, google-chrome-os, tooltip

I've started noticing black boxes with text on them popping up on various places throughout my screen. They sometimes look a little different but all of them dissapear when I try to screenshot, so it's hard to show. They also appear when I hover my cursor on my shelf, side panel, etc.How can I disable or block it, it's causing lots of sensory issues and nothing I'm doing including trying to block hover text is working.

I'm on the latest version of chromeOS.